# Unable to read configurations from local git repository using spring-cloud-config-server

Tags: java, git, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 2.4.5 and trying to configure spring cloud server to read property file from local git repository. Below links are for service startup and spring cloud server startup logs,

limits-service:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U6o2UzdHDquyzsyUv0Im3h0RqbFXaCJG/view?usp=sharing

spring-cloud-config-server:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A5J0S7sZRMQfeb2Hv94slgt4o5xtjsEo/view?usp=sharing

After all configurations, the URL, **http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default** returns 404 as below,

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu May 20 14:07:14 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Code components:

Class Limits:

```java
package com.home.microservices.limitsservice.bean;


public class Limits {

  private int minimum;
  private int maximum;

  public Limits() {
    super();
  }

  public Limits(int minimum, int maximum) {
    super();
    this.minimum = minimum;
    this.maximum = maximum;
  }

  public int getMinimum() {
    return minimum;
  }

  public void setMinimum(int minimum) {
    this.minimum = minimum;
  }

  public int getMaximum() {
    return maximum;
  }

  public void setMaximum(int maximum) {
    this.maximum = maximum;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Limits [minimum=" + minimum + ", maximum=" + maximum + "]";
  }
}
```

Controller:

```java
package com.home.microservices.limitsservice.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.home.microservices.limitsservice.bean.Limits;
import com.home.microservices.limitsservice.Configuration;

@RestController
public class LimitsController {

  @Autowired
  private Configuration configuration;

  @GetMapping("/limits")
  public Limits retrieveLimits() {
    return new Limits(configuration.getMinimum(), configuration.getMaximum());
  }
}
```

Configuration:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("limits-service")
public class Configuration {

  private int minimum;
  private int maximum;
  
  public int getMinimum() {
    return minimum;
  }

  public void setMinimum(int minimum) {
    this.minimum = minimum;
  }

  public int getMaximum() {
    return maximum;
  }

  public void setMaximum(int maximum) {
    this.maximum = maximum;
  }
}
```

application.properties(limits-service):

```
logging.level.org.springframework = debug
spring.application.name=limits-service
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
limits-service.minimum=3
limits-service.maximum=997
```

pom.xml dependencies(limits-service):

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```java
class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication:

@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

application.properties(spring-cloud-config-server):

```
logging.level.org.springframework = debug
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///D:/Learning/Microservices/git-localconfig-repo
spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false
```

pom.xml dependencies(spring-cloud-config-server):

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Git repo directory location(I use Windows):

```
D:\Learning\Microservices\git-localconfig-repo\limits-service.properties
```

Comment: please add configuration file or application.properties your config-server

Comment: @Zaur I have added the configuration file to config server
------------------------


Abhishek@LAPTOP-LEB9S56P MINGW64 /d/Learning/Microservices/git-localconfig-repo (master)
$ ls
limits-service.properties

-----------------------

Abhishek@LAPTOP-LEB9S56P MINGW64 /d/Learning/Microservices/git-localconfig-repo (master)
$ git commit
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Please add main class @EnableConfigServer

Answer (score 0):

Your read the application.properties file add Component field @value

```
 @Component
 @PropertySource("file:D:\Learning\Microservices\git-localconfig- 
 repo\application.properties")
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="limits-service")
 public class Configuration {

 @Value("${minimum}")
 private int minimum;
 @Value("${maximum}")
 private int maximum;

 public int getMinimum() {
 return minimum;
 }

 public void setMinimum(int minimum) {
 this.minimum = minimum;
 }

 public int getMaximum() {
 return maximum;
 }

 public void setMaximum(int maximum) {
  this.maximum = maximum;
  }
 }
```

This file  application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework = debug
spring.application.name=limits-service
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
limits-service.minimum=3
limits-service.maximum=997
```

Comment: please make a turn Let's solve the problem

Comment: will I have to create limits-server.properties under /limits-service/src/main/resources?

Comment: you should get your minimum and maximum values ​​from where

Comment: Where appliaciton.properties (limits.properties)?

Comment: I want to get these values from local GIT repository which is created at D:\Learning\Microservices\git-localconfig-repo.

Comment: then write that way

Comment: At that location I have created limits-service.properties and added, committed it to git.

Comment: @PropertySource path add your git repos way

Comment: Very simple thing

Comment: ```
@Component
@PropertySource("D:/Learning/Microservices/git-localconfig-repo/limits-service.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="limits-service")
public class Configuration {
 @Value("${minimum}")
 private int minimum;
 @Value("${maximum}")
 private int maximum;
```

Comment: Exception after this change,
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [D:/Learning/Microservices/git-localconfig-repo/limits-service.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: please add classpath

Comment: Change:

`@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="limits-service")
public class Configuration {
 @Value("${minimum}")
 private int minimum;
 @Value("${maximum}")
 private int maximum;`


application.properties:
`logging.level.org.springframework = debug
spring.application.name=limits-service
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
minimum=3
maximum=997`

Comment: After this change I am able to retrieve values from application. properties and the URL, http://localhost:8080/limits is working fine but still the URL, http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default to retrieve values from GIT repository is returning 404

Comment: Please check my edtiting answer

Comment: add that file where your minimum and maximum are PropertySoruce a

Comment: `
@Component
@PropertySource("file:D://Learning//Microservices//git-localconfig-repo//limits-service.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="limits-service")
public class Configuration {
 @Value("${minimum}")
 private int minimum;
 @Value("${maximum}")
 private int maximum;
`

Comment: please add project github and share link

Comment: Added,
https://github.com/agaikwad07-alt/Microservices.git

Comment: why maximum and minimum values in two properties application.prooperties and limits-service.properties ?

Comment: maximum and minimum values can be removed from application.properties as I don't want to read them from the file. I want to read them from limits-service.properties which is present in my local git repo(D://Learning//Microservices//git-localconfig-repo//limits-service.properties).

Comment: Please read this https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-micro-services-spring-cloud-config-ser

Comment: I have tried after removing maximum and minimum values from application.properties. There is no change in result

Comment: Will create a new project and check